# R: applying a function on whole dataset to find points within a circle

Tags: r

I have a difficulty with application of the data frame on my function in R. I have a data.frame with three columns ID of a point, its location on x axis and its location on y axis. All I need to do is to find for a given point IDs of points that lies in its neighborhood. I've made the function that shows whether the point lies within a circle where the center is a location of observed point and returns it's ID if true.

Here is my code:

```
point_id <- locationdata$point_id
x_loc <- locationdata$x_loc
y_loc <- locationdata$y_loc

locdata <- data.frame(point_id, x_loc, y_loc)

#radius set to1km
incircle3 <- function(x_loc, y_loc, center_x, center_y, pointid, r = 1000000){

        dx = (x_loc-center_x)
        dy = (y_loc-center_y)


        if (b <- dx^2 + dy^2 <= r^2){
                print(shopid)}  ##else {print('')}

}
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to apply this function on the whole data frame. So once I enter the locations of the observed point it would return me IDs of all points that lies in the neighborhood. Ideally I would need to find this relation for all the points automatically. So it would return me the points that lies in the neighborhood of each point from the dataset. Previously I have been inserting the center_x and center_y manually.

Thank you very much for your advices in advance!

Comment: The `apply` family of functions is what you're looking for. Your function should return a list() though. It should look something like `locdata$in_circle <- apply(locdata, 1, incircle3, y_loc)`  (the first parameter `x_loc` is passed into the function by default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tackle this with R's `dist` function:

```
# set the random seed and create some dummy data

set.seed(101)
dummy <- data.frame(id=1:100, x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
> head(dummy)
  id          x          y
1  1 0.37219838 0.12501937
2  2 0.04382482 0.02332669
3  3 0.70968402 0.39186128
4  4 0.65769040 0.85959857
5  5 0.24985572 0.71833452
6  6 0.30005483 0.33939503
```

Call the `dist` function which returns a `dist` object. The default distance metric is Euclidean which is what you have coded in your question.

```
dists <- dist(dummy[,2:3])
```

Loop over the distance matrix and return the indices for each id that are within some constant distance:

```
neighbors <- apply(as.matrix(dists), 1, function(x) which(x < 0.33))
> neighbors[[1]]
 1  6  7  8 19 23 30 32 33 34 42 44 46 51 55 87 88 91 94 99
```

Here's a modification to handle volatile ids:

```
    set.seed(101)
    dummy <- data.frame(id=sample(1:100, 100), x=runif(100), y=runif(100))
    > head(dummy)
      id          x          y
    1 38 0.12501937 0.60567568
    2  5 0.02332669 0.56259740
    3 70 0.39186128 0.27685556
    4 64 0.85959857 0.22614243
    5 24 0.71833452 0.98355758
    6 29 0.33939503 0.09838715

    dists <- dist(dummy[,2:3])

    neighbors <- apply(as.matrix(dists), 1, function(x) {
      dummy$id[which(x < 0.33)]
    })
    names(neighbors) <- dummy$id

    > neighbors[['38']]
     [1] 38  5 55 80 63 76 17 71 47 11 88 13 41 21 36 31 73 61 99 59 39 89 94 12 18  3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. Actually in my data the id numbers are quite volatile ie. first one is 589 than the next one is 860 and so on. Would there be any way to add the information about the id so I could know the exact id values? Thank you once again!

Comment: Hey-a, Chewie, I expanded on the example to make it work with volatile indices